How to group below data into row and column in postgresql
[
    {
        name: 'Ali', 
        summaries: 
        [
            {claim: 'a' , balance: 1}, 
            {claim: 'b' , balance: 1}
        ]
    },
    {
        name: 'Abu', 
        summaries: 
        [
            {claim: 'a' , balance: 1}, 
            {claim: 'b' , balance: 1}
        ]
    }
]

the expected result should be showing as below



name
summaries




ali
{claim: 'a' , balance: 1}


abu
{claim: 'a' , balance: 1}




Your question lacks sufficient detail. You've tagged postgresql,  but it appears that the input value is from another environment; e.g., Ruby on Rails. Please add additional details including code you've used when attempting to achieve the desired results.

What about claim "b"? Are we to understand you want to exclude it? Please, offer more details.
